# Make a reflection class pass type hinting

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit, type-hinting

I want to unit test a class and I need to mock entities.
To sum up, I need to make a reflection class of `childEntity` in order to set its ID and then call

```
parentEntity->addChild($childEntity)
```

The problem is `addChild()` is type hinted on `childEntity` and throws an exception when I send a `ReflectionClass`
Is there any way to trick the method into thinking the parameter is of a valid class ?

EDIT : I forgot to mention that `setId()` in `childEntity` doesn't exist. It's an auto-increment field handled by Doctrine.

Comment: Are you using PHPUnit ? If yes, see [Test doubles](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html)

You can use it like this `$stub = $this->getMockBuilder($childEntityClassName)->getMock();`

The createMock($type) and getMockBuilder($type) methods provided by PHPUnit can be used in a test to automatically generate an object that can act as a test double for the specified original type (interface or class name). This test double object can be used in every context where an object of the original type is expected or required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [ReflectionProperty::setValue](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setvalue.php) you set value to the property of the instance of the class. Then you pass the instance itself as the argument, not the Reflection class. E.g.:

```
$reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass('ChildEntity');
$childEntity = new ChildEntity();

$reflectionProperty = $reflectionClass->getProperty('ID');
$reflectionProperty->setAccessible(true);
$reflectionProperty->setValue($childEntity, 1);

$parentEntity->addChild($childEntity);
```

It is not a mock though.

There is a working example to play with: https://repl.it/MTWf

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately, `setId` is non-existent, so this creates an error stating `Cannot access non-public member`

Comment: @Hakim, I'm not sure where `setId` popped up from. I understand that the ID is private and cannot be set directly to the object, so you want to employ Reflection functionality. My assumption was you have read the documentation behind the link I posted in the answer, as it seems you have a general misunderstanding of how reflection works. Anyway check my updated code how to use reflection to set value to private property.

Comment: I don't know what I did before, but it seems too work ! Thank you very much